# Automate OCX wrapper from C++ to C++ using visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ocx

I am developing an OCX with some DISP_FUNCTION_ID defined. 
How could I automatically generate a wrapper for it to be used in an MFC C++ Dialog so it can be autoregenerated when I add functions to my OCX?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use dual interfaces instead.  Write their declaration in IDL so you can create a type library with midl.exe.  Which you can then [#import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) into the client app, that automatically generates a wrapper based on the _com_ptr_t class.  Dual interfaces are automatically generated when you use the ATL Object wizard.

Comment: How can I generate the IDL file from the OCX?

Answer (score -1):

I used ClassWizard to generate the class from a type library.

> To do this, open ClassWizard, and
>   press "Add Class", selecting "From a
>   type library" from the drop down list.
>   Locate your type library, and then
>   select all the classes from the list
>   it presents to you.
>
> Each of the classes is derived from
>   COleDispatchDriver. You can use the
>   CreateDispatch() method of the class
>   to create an instance of the class.

[Source](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/CPP/Q_20666266.html)

Comment: Do not link to sites requiring (paid) membership.